# jPlayer: Get current volume

Tags: javascript, jplayer

I am trying to save the current volume of my jPlayer to a cookie. This is my code.

```
//Save the jPlayer volume when it changes. 
$("#startpage_jplayer").bind($.jPlayer.event.volumechange, function(event){

    //Cache the volume value.
    var new_volume = event.jPlayer.options.volume;

    //Store the volume in a cookie.
    $.cookie('jp_volume', new_volume, { expires: 7, path: '/'});

});
```

Each time the volume changes I get that there is no options property.
I suppose they moved the property but it's really hard to find the new one.

Thank you for your time.

[Console Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtwU9.png)

Comment: Post your full jPlayer code because this code is fine. http://jsfiddle.net/chq6uu16/27/

Where are you binding this?

Comment: @MartinMazzaDawson thank you for time. It seems that my server "refused" to clear the JS cache for some time. Problem solved !

Answer (score 0):

I used some deprecated event detection methods before and when I updated my code, my server did not clear the cache after flushing it 5 times.

The code is fine, thus problem solved !